# About Special and Extra-special $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, terminology, math-history, p-groups

> A $p$-group $G$ is said to be special $p$-group if $Z(G)=[G,G]=$ elementary abelian.
>
> A $p$-group $G$ is said to be extra-special if $Z(G)=[G,G]=$ elementary abelian of order $p$.

The questions I am considering are not too much technical; it is about terminology, and some history. Also, I didn't find any reference for them in old books of Group Theory and algebra. I couldn't ask to anyone around me, as they are experts in subjects other than Algebra, hence posted here.

**Q.1** When the terminologies of *special $p$-groups* and *extra-special $p$-groups* were introduced?

**Q.2** Is there any reason why special $p$-groups are called *special*? (I mean, Groups with certain interesting property may be termed as *special*, but what is reason to call special $p$-groups as *special*?)